# Operator of differentiation

Tags: functional-analysis

Okay I need to know once and for all how to properly show that $L$ is closed and not continuous, $L_n$ is bounded for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $L_n \to L$ pointwise when $n \to \infty$, $L_n$ doesn't converge to $L$ with respect to $\| \cdot \|_{\mathrm{op}}$. I have this example:

Consider for $X = (C^0([0,1]), \| \cdot \|_\infty)$ the subspace $D = C^1([0,1]) \subset X$. The operators $L, L_n \colon D \to X$ are defined as $Lf := f'$ and
$$
  (L_n f)(t)
  :=
  \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{f(t)-f(t-\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}
    & \text{for $t \in [\frac{1}{n}, 1]$},
    \\[1em] % some extre spacing between the two cases
    \dfrac{f(\frac{1}{n}) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}
    & \text{else}.
  \end{cases}
$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
I know this is a big ask, I just want to know, how do you prove these things, so if anyone has any ideas, hints, anything I will be grateful.

Comment: Which operator do you want to show it's closed? Closed in the sense that it sends closed subsets to closed subsets or closed in the sense that it's graph is closed? Do you want to show convergence between the operators? What kind of convergence? Also, showing an operator is bounded and not continuous is impossible, since for linear operators continuous is equivalent to bounded... Could you make the question clearer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first claim is that the operators $L_n$ are all bounded in operator norm. This is relatively easy to prove: the difference of two bounded operators is bounded, and dividing by a constant $\frac 1 n$ doesn't change the operator being bounded.

The next claim is that $L_n \to L$ pointwise. This is also pretty simple. Pointwise convergence just requires that if we fix $f$ and $t$ then we get $L_n(f)(t) \to L(f)(t)$. That's true basically by definition of derivatives, since $f'(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(t) - f(t-\frac 1 n)}{1/n}$.

Now for the tricky part: showing that $L_n$ doesn't converge to $L$. To show this, define functions $f_n \in D$ such that

1. $f_n(t) = 0$ for $0 \le t \le 1-\frac 1 {2n}$
2. $f_n(1) = 1$
3. In the interval $(1 - \frac{1}{2n}, 1)$, I require $0 \le f_n(t) \le 1$. Besides that, just choose any way to connect the two sides while making $f_n \in C^1$. For example, we could use $f_n(t) = 4n^2 \left(t-1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2$. The exact definition won't matter though.

By definition of the operator norm, $\|L - L_n\|_{op} \ge \frac{\|L(f_n) - L_n(f_n)\|_\infty}{\|f_n\|_\infty}.$ I'll show that the RHS does not converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, thus proving that $L_n \not \to L$.

First, the denominator: $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$ since that's the largest absolute value $f_n$ takes.

Next, the numerator.

- Evaluating $\|L_n(f_n)\|_\infty$ comes down to finding $t$ such that $\left|f_n(t) - f_n(t - \frac 1 n)\right|$ is as big as possible. The way I constructed $f_n$ means that the best choice is $t=1$, giving a norm of $\|L_n(f_n)\|_\infty = n \left( f_n(1) - f_n(1 - \frac 1 n)\right) = n \left(1\right) = n$.
- Evaluating $\|L(f_n)\|_\infty$ means finding the largest absolute value of $f_n'$. I  know $f_n(1-\frac 1 {2n}) = 0$ and $f_n(1) = 1$, so by Mean Value Theorem I know there's some $t^* \in \left(1 - \frac 1 n, 1\right)$ satisfying $f_n'(t^*) \ge \frac{1}{1/2n} = 2n$. In other words, $\|L(f_n)\|_\infty \ge 2n$.
- Putting those together: $\|L(f_n) - L_n(f_n)\|_\infty \ge \|L(f_n)\|_\infty - \|L_n(f_n)\|_\infty \ge 2n - n = n$.

Now combine everything:
$$
\begin{align*}
\|L-L_n\|_{op} &\ge \frac{\|L(f_n) - L_n(f_n)\|_\infty}{\|f_n\|_\infty} \\
&\ge \frac{n}{1} = n
\end{align*}
$$
In particular, we do NOT have $\|L-L_n\|_{op} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so $L_n \not \to L$ in operator-norm.

---

An obvious followup question would be: How did I think of choosing those particular functions $f_n$? My answer is: to disprove the convergence, I need to choose functions such that $\|L_n(f_n)\|_\infty$ is very different from $\|L(f_n)\|_\infty$. The operators $L_n$ are good approximations to $L$ if the function values' swings happen across larger ranges (length at least $\frac 1 n$), so I tried choosing functions $f_n$ that change very suddenly across an interval with size significantly smaller than $\frac 1 n$.

---

**Edit:** Actually, $L$ is not a continuous (aka bounded) operator at all. Taking this route could have saved me a bunch of trouble in the proof above. Let me explain.

To show $L$ is not a bounded operator: Choose functions $f_n \in D$ such that $\|f_n(t)\| \le 1$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ but $f_n'(t) \ge n$ for at least one value $t$. (Finding such functions is easy; the functions I used in my proof above work fine.) Then $\frac{\|L(f_n)\|_\infty}{\|f_n\|_\infty} \ge n$, so if $\|L\|_{op}$ existed then it would need to be $\ge n$ for all integers $n$. We conclude $L$ is unbounded.

To show it's not possible for bounded operators to converge in op-norm to an unbounded operator: We have $L_n$ bounded and $L$ unbounded. If $L_n - L$ were bounded, then we'd have $\|L\|_{op} \le \|L_n\|_{op} + \|L-L_n\|_{op} < \infty$ using the triangle inequality, so $L$ would be bounded which is a contradiction. Therefore $L_n-L$ is unbounded for all $n$, so we certainly don't have $\|L_n - L\|_{op} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

So $L$ is not a continuous operator and $L_n$ don't converge to $L$ in op-norm even though $L_n \to L$ pointwise.

Finally, we show $L$ is closed. Let $g_n$ be some sequence of functions in $D$ such that $g_n \to g$ and $g_n' \to h$ for some $g, h \in X$. We need to show $g \in D$ and $g' = h$. To show this, we note that convergence in $\infty$-norm is the same as [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition) of functions. If the original functions converge to $g$ and the derivatives converge uniformly to $h$, then a standard theorem says $g$ is differentiable and $g' = h$, which is what we needed to prove. If you want to read about that theorem, you could check Theorem 6.3.1 [here](https://math.byu.edu/%7Ebakker/M341/Lectures/Lec29.pdf) or this section on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability).

Comment: Thank you so much and does that mean if Ln doesn't converge to L that Ln to L is still pointwise when n is to infinity?? Or no?

Comment: $L_n$ does converge to $L$ pointwise. I added a new paragraph near the top with a brief explanation.

Comment: Oh, okay,  what about if L is closed but not continuous, was the previous commentator correct in stating that it is impossible?

Comment: I've added to my answer. $L$ is not continuous, and actually that can be used to give a shorter proof of the original statement. I don't know what "$L$ is closed" would mean; I don't think that's a commonly used term but if you explain what you mean by it then maybe I or someone else could help you.

Comment: So, a linear operator
T : D → F is called closed, if for each sequence (xn) ⊂ D we have that xn → x, T xn → y
imply x ∈ D and T x = y.
This means, a closed operator is an operator T : D → F which graph is closed. This is the definition, but I am just not sure how it fits this situation

Comment: Ah, you're right. OK, I've edited my answer again to also prove $L$ is closed.